# In a socket.recv(1024), how can I search for a specific word inside of it?

Tags: python, sockets

I have a simple banner grabber. If I grab a banner from Google, I receive something back.

I want to find a specific word inside the socket data? How can I do that?

**My Banner grabber:**

```
import socket
import ipaddress

import socket
host = "www.google.nl"
port = 80
addr = (host, port)
s = socket.socket()
s.connect (addr)
s.send(b'GET / HTTP/1.1\n\n\n')
print(s.recv(1024))
```

**Banner I receive from Google.nl (s.recv(1024)):**

> `b'HTTP/1.1 302 Found\r\nCache-Control: private\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\nReferrer-Policy: no-referrer\r\nLocation: http://www.google.nl/?gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=XrAKWpHeJ9GC3gOB_ZWoBg\r\nContent-Length: 268\r\nDate: Tue, 14 Nov 2017 08:59:10 GMT\r\n\r\n<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">\n<TITLE>302 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>\n<H1>302 Moved</H1>\nThe document has moved\n<A HREF="http://www.google.nl/?gfe_rd=cr&amp;dcr=0&amp;ei=XrAKWpHeJ9GC3gOB_ZWoBg">here</A>.\r\n</BODY></HTML>\r\n'`

**What I want:**

```
If "Document" is in s.recv(1024):
print ("Document is found in the banner!")

Else:
print ("No keyword found")
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you write the pseudo code if else construct in python (simple change), store the received bytes in variable and naively transform them to string, you can continue your programming with:

```
import socket
host = "www.google.nl"
port = 80
addr = (host, port)
s = socket.socket()
s.connect(addr)
s.send(b'GET / HTTP/1.1\n\n\n')
b_text = s.recv(1024)
print(b_text)
if "Document" in str(b_text):
    print("Document is found in the banner!")
else:
    print("No keyword found")
```

In case you want to spare the variable (I do not know the use case), a code snippet working "directly on the result of the s.recv() call" is:

```
import socket
host = "www.google.nl"
port = 80
addr = (host, port)
s = socket.socket()
s.connect(addr)
s.send(b'GET / HTTP/1.1\n\n\n')
if "Document" in str(s.recv(1024)):
    print("Document is found in the banner!")
else:
    print("No keyword found")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried your first solution however, it does not print out anything. in the if else section: https://gyazo.com/5be21d3e6c6f2645bbf0a7b8df4460ee

Comment: @MertCakir Well, you did not copy my solution, but only the last lines. In the supplied screenvideocapture, I spot that you first still print s.recv(1024). After that it should not yield the same content, when storing the next call to s.recv(1024) into a variable, you check against ;-)

Comment: I see! I removed the print banner section and then it worked! Thank you very much for your help! :)

Comment: @MertCakir you are welcome to further check pep8 for python style and ease of reading, but foremost, sockets are sensitive to operational errors in understanding and buffers might not contain the whole response, etc. so good luck in continuing on your path

Comment: I will. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Better to use the right tool for the job instead of low-level sockets.  `requests` is a popular 3rd party library for making HTTP requests.

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get('http://www.google.nl')
>>> r.headers
{'Date': 'Tue, 14 Nov 2017 17:13:33 GMT', 'Expires': '-1', 'Cache-Control': 'private, max-age=0', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; char
set=ISO-8859-1', 'P3P': 'CP="This is not a P3P policy! See g.co/p3phelp for more info."', 'Server': 'gws', 'Content-Length': '5129
', 'X-XSS-Protection': '1; mode=block', 'X-Frame-Options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'Via': '1.1 jfdmzpr06', 'Connection': 'Keep-Alive', 'Cont
ent-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Set-Cookie': '1P_JAR=2017-11-14-17; expires=Thu, 14-Dec-2017 17:13:33 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.nl, NID=
117=Sa3F7Bq4oXkQdcBu5OXCM3AdfyGZbxABbYqFMenMm-Ru4nITdC8tQujRxLJPl3aUG8ksQM-uDF56jlDrk0Hm9KMVkbOcb51K0oyys0PFU3ZEaSS5TnzBGk_dOYmK4X
vS; expires=Wed, 16-May-2018 17:13:33 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.nl; HttpOnly'}
>>> r.status_code
200
>>> r.text[:1000]
'<!doctype html><html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" lang="en"><head><meta content="Search the world\'s informa
tion, including webpages, images, videos and more. Google has many special features to help you find exactly what you\'re looking
for." name="description"><meta content="noodp" name="robots"><meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"><m
eta content="/logos/doodles/2017/131st-anniversary-of-the-hole-puncher-5763551741345792.3-law.gif" itemprop="image"><meta content=
"131st Anniversary of the Hole Puncher" property="twitter:title"><meta content="131st Anniversary of the Hole Puncher #GoogleDoodl
e" property="twitter:description"><meta content="131st Anniversary of the Hole Puncher #GoogleDoodle" property="og:description"><m
eta content="summary_large_image" property="twitter:card"><meta content="@GoogleDoodles" property="twitter:site"><meta content="ht
tps://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2017/131st-anniversary-of-the-hole-puncher-576355174134579'
>>> 'History' in r.text
True
```